# Finding the column name when an error occurs in SSIS data flow

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis-2012

Well, I am trying to capture some error information after performing some validation steps. I would like to export that info and use it to highlight the error data in an excel table. But that is just some context.
My problem is about not being able to capture the column name on SSIS 2012 data flow.
I am new to VB.NET, though I have familiarity with VBA and some experience with C#.

I sucessfully captured the row and error description following some simple tutorials.
Now, for the columnn name part i found this useful post:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/helloworld/2008/08/01/how-to-find-out-which-column-caused-ssis-to-fail/

It gives a query ("in LINQ") that provides a dictionary that would help me find the info I need by using Row.ErrorCode.ErrorColumn as a key.

Well, the thing is that the code is in C# and I already have a good lot of my code in VB.NET. I tried to "translate it" without success.

Before trying to change all my code to C#, I thought of asking for some help debugging my attempt.

Code in c#

```
private Dictionary<long, string> GetLineageIdAndColumnMapping(string SSISFilename)

{

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(SSISFilename);

    Dictionary<long, string> LineageColumn = new Dictionary<long, string>();

    var LineageNodes = from Nodes in xdoc.Descendants()

                       where Nodes.Attribute("lineageId") != null &&

                             Nodes.Attribute("lineageId").Value != String.Empty &&

                             Nodes.Attribute("name") != null &&

                             Nodes.Attribute("name").Value != String.Empty

                       select new

                       {

                           LineageId = Convert.ToInt64(Nodes.Attribute("lineageId").Value),

                           ColumnName = Nodes.Attribute("name").Value

                       };


    foreach (var Item in LineageNodes)

        LineageColumn.Add(Item.LineageId, Item.ColumnName);


    return LineageColumn;

}
```

My code in VB.NET (the GetLineageIdAndColumnMapping function is the one I tried to translate):

```
  Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        Dim ColumnMapping As Dictionary(Of Long, String) = New Dictionary(Of Long, String)
        Dim packageFilename As String = "ThePath"

        Row.ErrorDescription = ComponentMetaData.GetErrorDescription(Row.ErrorCode)
        ColumnMapping = GetLineageIdAndColumnMapping(packageFilename)
        ColumnMapping.TryGetValue(Row.ErrorColumn, columnName)
        Row.ErrorColumnName = columnName
    End Sub

    Public Function GetLineageIdAndColumnMapping(SSISFilename As String) As Dictionary(Of Long, String)

        Dim xdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
        Dim LineageColumn As Dictionary(Of Long, String) = New Dictionary(Of Long, String)

        xdoc.LoadXml(SSISFilename)

        Dim LineageNodes As List(Of XmlElement) = From Nodes In xdoc.ChildNodes _
                            Where Not (IsDBNull(Nodes.Attribute("lineageId"))) _
                            Select New With {.LineageId = Convert.ToInt64(Nodes.Attribute("lineageId").Value), .ColumnName = Nodes.Attribute("name").Value}

        Dim Item As XmlElement
        For Each Item In LineageNodes
            LineageColumn.Add(Long.Parse(Item.GetAttribute("linageId")), Item.GetAttribute("name"))
        Next

        Return LineageColumn

    End Function
```

Well, I had to "change" some classes and use what I believed to be their equivalents.
I expected to output the column name using the query/dictionary (and the error description, which is working fine)

I have 5 late bound resolution warnings on the query line (Dim LineageNodes ....).
Also, I have an extra Implicit conversion warning on that same line:

```
(Warning    1   Implicit conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of <anonymous type>)' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Xml.XmlElement)'.[...])
```

That is why I believe the problem is there, though I ran out of ideas and pretty much got stuck.

Besides that, I have a warning about x64/x86 environment:

```
(Warning    7   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the 
reference "Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91", "x86". 
This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor 
architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a 
dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
    SC_72778091ee9047d689e5cd5fea6e57da)
```

I am using Excel (32 bits) as a source so experimenting with that would require changing the whole SSIS project setup. Though I may try that if I don't think of anything else.

On execution the code throws an exception (Script Component: Runtime Error):

```
"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

"   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
   at SC_72778091ee9047d689e5cd5fea6e57da.ScriptMain.GetLineageIdAndColumnMapping(String SSISFilename)
   at SC_72778091ee9047d689e5cd5fea6e57da.ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
   at SC_72778091ee9047d689e5cd5fea6e57da.UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
   at SC_72778091ee9047d689e5cd5fea6e57da.UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, String InputName, PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)"
```

I hope that helps explaining the problem. I hope anyone with some knowledge of C# and/or VB.NET could shed some light on the matter.

Thank you in advance for any feedback!

Comment: Firstly, this isn't a code conversion service.  There are plenty of tools out there that do that.  Google is your friend there.  However, eyeballing what you've given use I don't really see any syntax problems.  Going by the error message, I would question the stage of the xml you are trying to read.  Have you tried some basic debugging to ensure it is actually being loaded correctly?

Comment: The xml is loaded correctly. The xml is the package/dtsx itself.
I'll try and find some conversion tool as you suggested.